# python-pyvtk throws warning about header

Tags: python, vtk

The following code lines generate warnings:

```
theVtkData = pyvtk.VtkData(
    pyvtk.RectilinearGrid(range(Nx), range(Ny), range(Nz)),
    pyvtk.PointData(pyvtk.Vectors(vectorList, 'spins')),
    header = 'myheader')
```

And this is the warning:

```
VtkData.__init__.warning:
    Using header='Really cool data'
```

I don't get why. The header 'myheader' is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

The PyVTK [source](http://code.google.com/p/pyvtk/source/browse/lib/__init__.py) and documentation are not particularly clear. However, it seems that the header string must be specified as a *positional*, not *keyword*, argument. So, try using

```
theVtkData = pyvtk.VtkData(
    pyvtk.RectilinearGrid(range(Nx), range(Ny), range(Nz)),
    pyvtk.PointData(pyvtk.Vectors(vectorList, 'spins')),
    'myheader')
```

For more information, see line 149 of the source for where `header` is set to `Really cool data`. This is part of a `for` block which loops over `args`, where the constructor for `VtkData` has the signature `VtkData(self, *args, **kws)`. It seems that the `**kws` argument is used for only one keyword argument, `only_structure`.